# Working with dates in PHP from day to night

Tags: php

There is a page where the user selects a period (dates)using datepicker.
There is a file handler for these received data, it converts them there, then..
There is an array of pre-known periods (in the same format as we converted the period received from the user), there are 5 of them, I attach a screenshot [range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQnWY.png), using a script (which I will also attach) we find the number of days" captured " by the user in previously defined periods.[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F8A7.png)

Now the problem is that you need to determine how many nights it will be for each period, and the problem is that:
You need to calculate the cost of the room, knowing the number of people, knowing the cost of the room in the current period (if you iterate in a cycle) and knowing the number of nights in this period.

Price = number of people * (room rate in the current period * number of nights in the current period)

There is one hitch, you can see periods in the screenshot, and you need to take into account the fact that the user can choose, for example, the date from June 9 to June 11, in this case, the resulting array of periods we will have $periods = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0], but, in total, it should turn out that it is 1 night out of 1 range and 1 night out of 2.

code: 
array of ranges:

```
$intervals = [
            '25.05-09.06',
            '10.06-30.06',
            '01.07-24.08',
            '25.08-14.09',
            '15.09-30.09'
        ];
```

script for getting days in periods:

```
$range_array = explode('-', $range); // разбиваем строку на 2 части (дата начала и конца)
$target_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m', $range_array[0]); // создаем объект дата-время по нужному формату
$target_end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m', $range_array[1]);

foreach ($intervals as $interval) { // работаем с каждым интервалом
    $interval_array = explode('-', $interval); // разбиваем строку интервала на части
    $interval_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m', $interval_array[0]);
    $interval_end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m', $interval_array[1]);
    $interval_end->modify('+1 day'); // затычка т. к daterange не включает последний день

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // устанавливаем интервал 1 день
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($interval_start, $interval, $interval_end); // разбивает дату на интервалы

     $count_includes_days = 0; // счетчик дней, которые входят в $range
     foreach ($daterange as $date) { // проходимся по каждому дню интервала
           if ($date >= $target_start && $date <= $target_end) $count_includes_days++; // увеличиваем, если дата интервала входит в $range
            //  if ($date >= $target_start && $date <= $target_end) $count_includes_days++; // увеличиваем, если дата интервала входит в $range // DEFAULT
            }

            $periods[] = $count_includes_days; // добавляем количество дней в новый массив
        }
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted. _Do not_ just show images of code.